# Evaluate $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{3+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt[3]{3}+\dots+\sqrt[n]{3}-n}{\ln n}$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

> Evaluate $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{3+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt[3]{3}+\dots+\sqrt[n]{3}-n}{\ln n}.$$

We haven't been taught how to do asymptotes, I think this problem should be solved using Cesaro-Stolz; $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{b_{n+1}-b_n}$$
Note that this is my second question on this site.It's the first year i learned about limits so don't expect that this problem solves in a hard way.

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1979619/calculate-a-given-limit

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you are correct, we can use [Stolz-Cesaro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem):
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n(\sqrt[k]{3}-1)}{\ln(n)}\stackrel{SC}{=}\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt[n+1]{3}-1}{\ln (n+1)-\ln(n)}=
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{e^{\left(\frac{\ln(3)}{n+1}\right)}-1}{\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}.$$
Now note that (see Arnaud Mortier's comment below)
$$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{e^{t}-1}{t}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{e^{t}-e^0}{t-0}=(e^t)'_{t=0}=e^0=1$$
and
$$
\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+t)}{t}=1=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+t)-\ln(1+0)}{t-0}=(\ln(1+t))'_{t=0}=\frac{1}{1+0}=1.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: what do you mean by $\exp(\ln(3)/n)-1$ , btw i understand the denumerator

Comment: i never used that relation before, i can't do it, and btw $\lim_n \ln(1+\frac{1}{n})=0 ?$

Comment: $$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{e^{t}-1}{t}=1\quad\mbox{and}\quad
\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+t)}{t}=1.$$

Comment: we've haven't been taught L'Hopital

Comment: Can you finish it using your method, i might understand or other viewers will

Comment: You can find the final result by using  $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{e^{t}-1}{t}=1$ and $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+t)}{t}=1$.

Comment: The two relations you mention can be seen as the definition of the derivative applied to the maps $e^t$  and ln$(1+t)$ at $0$.

Comment: @RobertZ  I've managed to reach $$n(e^{\frac{\ln 3}{n+1}}-1)$$ .Now what?

Comment: Fine. Now $n(e^{\frac{\ln 3}{n+1}}-1)=\frac{\ln(3)n}{n+1}\cdot \frac{e^{\frac{\ln 3}{n+1}}-1}{\frac{\ln(3)}{n+1}}\to ?$

Comment: $$n(e^{\frac{\ln 3}{n+1}}-1)=\frac{\ln(3)n}{n+1}\cdot \frac{e^{\frac{\ln 3}{n+1}}-1}{\frac{\ln(3)}{n+1}}\to 1$$ I appreciate your help

Comment: Probably you mean
$$n(e^{\frac{\ln 3}{n+1}}-1)=\frac{\ln(3)n}{n+1}\cdot \frac{e^{\frac{\ln 3}{n+1}}-1}{\frac{\ln(3)}{n+1}}\to \ln(3)\cdot 1=\ln(3)$$

Answer (score 5):

> I thought it might be of interest to present an approach that does ***not*** rely on the [Stolz-Cesaro Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem_(the_%E2%88%99/%E2%88%9E_case)), but rather uses only (i) a pair of inequalities of the exponential function, (ii) a result from the integral test, and (iii) the squeeze theorem.  To that end, we present two primers with references to their proofs.

---

**PRIMER $(1)$:**

In [THIS ANSWER](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263), I showed using on the limit definition of the integral test and Bernoulli's Inequality that the exponential function satisfies the inequalities

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{1+x\le e^x\le\frac{1}{1-x}} \tag1$$

for $x<1$.

---

**PRIMER $(2)$:**

As a result from the integral test ([SEE THIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence#Proof)), we have for a function $f(x)$ that is positive valued and monotonically decreasing for $x\ge N$

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\int_N^{n+1}f(x)\,dx\le \sum_{k=N}^n f(k)\le f(N)+\int_N^n f(x)\,dx}\tag2$$

---

**PROBLEM SOLUTION:**

Equipped with Primers $(1)$ and $(2)$, we are ready to proceed.

We begin with the function $f(x)=\sqrt[x]{3}-1=e^{\frac1x\log(3)}-1$ and write the sum of interest as $\sum_{k=1}^n f(k)=f(1)+\sum_{k=2}^n f(k)=2+\sum_{k=2}^n f(k)$.

Inasmuch as $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{2}{\log(n)}=0$, we analyze the limit $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sum_{k=2}^nf(k)}{\log(n)}$.

Applying the left-hand sides of $(1)$ and $(2)$, we see that

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=2}^nf(k)&\ge \int_2^{n+1}f(x)\,dx\\\\
&=\int_2^{n+1}(e^{\frac1x \log(3)}-1)\,dx\\\\
&\ge \int_2^{n+1}\frac{\log(3)}{x}\,dx\\\\
&=\log(3)(\log(n+1)-\log(2))\tag3
\end{align}$$

Applying the right-hand sides of $(1)$ and $(2)$, we see that

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=2}^nf(k)&\le (\sqrt3-1)+\int_2^{n}f(x)\,dx\\\\
&=(\sqrt 3-1)+\int_2^{n}(e^{\frac1x \log(3)}-1)\,dx\\\\
&\le (\sqrt 3-1)+\int_2^{n}\frac{\log(3)}{x-\log(3)}\,dx\\\\
&=(\sqrt 3-1)+\log(3)(\log(n-\log(3))-\log(2-\log(3)))\tag4
\end{align}$$

Dividing the expressions in $(3)$ and $(4)$ by $\log(n)$, and applying the squeeze theorem, we obtain the coveted result

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n(\sqrt[k]{3}-1)}{\log(n)}=\log(3)}$$

And we are done!

Comment: Very nice. The quality of contents and presentation of your answer is impressive. (+1)

Comment: @MarkusScheuer Thank you for the nice words Markus!  Very appreciative.

Comment: I second the comment from @MarkusScheuer +1. IMHO this seems to be novel use of the idea behind integral test.

Comment: @paramanandsingh Thank you my friend.  And Happy New Year to you.

Answer (score 1):

As noted already you are correct and by Stolz-Cesaro theorem:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n(\sqrt[k]{3}-1)}{\ln(n)}\stackrel{SC}{=}\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt[n+1]{3}-1}{\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}=\ln 3$$

indeed

$$\frac{\sqrt[n+1]{3}-1}{\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}= \frac{n\left(\sqrt[n+1]{3}-1\right)}{\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n} \to \ln 3$$

since by definition of $e$

$$\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\to \ln e=1$$

and by Taylor's espansion

$$\sqrt[n+1]{3}=e^{\frac{\ln 3}{n+1}}=1+\frac{\ln 3}{n+1}+o\left(\frac1n\right)$$

$$n\left(\sqrt[n+1]{3}-1\right)=\frac{n}{n+1}\ln 3+o(1)\to\ln 3$$